# How to link one file of code to another file of code or do i have to copy and paste that code on that file of code?

Tags: data-structures, hyperlink

Hi I am fairly new to coding and I am designing a webpage/app. I am basically trying to figure out how to link one file to another file of code. I have one file with some code that has my page design but I designed a hamburger drop down menu in another file. My question is can I just link that file to my home page file or do I have to re-code it on that page and every page after that?[Picture of code and files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwcpo.png)

Comment: Instead of sharing the screenshot of the code, share the text of the code. Also, while attaching an image, make sure it is visible in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be writing a HTML file. The traditional way to solve what you are looking for, is to bring another language into the mix, such as PHP, Ruby, Python, etc.

These languages need to run on a server. Instead of writing HTML directly, these languages write HTML on the fly for you.

Because of this feature, you can make re-usable parts of HTML and use them in multiple pages.

The switch to server-side programming languages is definitely a step up in complexity from HTML, but it's worth learning if this is your goal.

Comment: Is Javascript doing the same thing because I wrote some java code also for it or is not? Again I apologize if these questions seem stupid.

Comment: @SavageeCoding Javascript *could* do this, but only the server-side Node.js variant. Also, Java is a completely different language from Javascript. Java is probably not recommended for your first language.